# jQuery Array and Foreach

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my array and i need to do a foreach to display the image and such for each one.
Basically the array contains slides and slide information, i need to output a div for each one with the information in (which i can do if i knew how to access it).

```
var slides = new Array();
slides[1] = {slidetitle: 'title 1',
             slidetext: 'text 1',
             image1: '',
             magnifyposit: '',
             buttontext: 'button text 1',
             buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};
slides[2] = {slidetitle: 'title 2',
             slidetext: 'text 2',
             image1: '',
             magnifyposit: '',
             buttontext: 'button text 2',
             buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};
slides[3] = {slidetitle: 'title 3',
             slidetext: 'text 3',
             image1: '',
             magnifyposit: '',
             buttontext: 'button text 3',
             buttonurl: ''};
slides[4] = {slidetitle: 'title 4',
             slidetext: 'text 4',
             image1: '',
             magnifyposit: '',
             buttontext: 'button text 4',
             buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};
slides[5] = {slidetitle: 'title 5',
             slidetext: 'text 5',
             image1: '',
             magnifyposit: '',
             buttontext: 'button text 5',
             buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like this

```
$.each(slides,function(i,obj){
   //here  obj is object element of slides array

  // access properties of the object 
  // in current iteration like obj.slidetitle,obj.slidetext etc

});
```

**Note:** You should start array index at 0.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/dHEq8/)

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to note.  You'll want to start your array at index 0.  Here is the full code and jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/gKgns/

```
var slides = new Array();

slides[0] = {slidetitle: 'title 1',
                         slidetext: 'text 1',
                         image1: '',
                         magnifyposit: '',
                         buttontext: 'button text 1',
                         buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};

slides[1] = {slidetitle: 'title 1',
                         slidetext: 'text 1',
                         image1: '',
                         magnifyposit: '',
                         buttontext: 'button text 1',
                         buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};

slides[2] = {slidetitle: 'title 2',
                         slidetext: 'text 2',
                         image1: '',
                         magnifyposit: '',
                         buttontext: 'button text 2',
                         buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};

slides[3] = {slidetitle: 'title 3',
                         slidetext: 'text 3',
                         image1: '',
                         magnifyposit: '',
                         buttontext: 'button text 3',
                         buttonurl: ''};

slides[4] = {slidetitle: 'title 4',
                         slidetext: 'text 4',
                         image1: '',
                         magnifyposit: '',
                         buttontext: 'button text 4',
                         buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};

 slides[5] = {slidetitle: 'title 5',
                         slidetext: 'text 5',
                         image1: '',
                         magnifyposit: '',
                         buttontext: 'button text 5',
                         buttonurl: 'http://www.google.com'};      

var $container= $('#container');
$.each(slides, function(index, value) { 
   var $div = $('<div>' + value.slidetitle + '</div>');
   $container.append($div);
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Basically you must create a table with an empty `tbody`, `tbody` must have an id set up in order to select it later.

```
$.each(slides, function (index, value) {
    var row = '<tr><td>value.title</td></tr>'
    + '<tr><td>value.text</td></tr>';

    $('#tableBody').append(row);
}
```

- Where value is your Array object.